# Best way to Migrate Angular JS framework version from 1.2.2 to latest 1.4.8?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, migration

What should be the planning to Migrate Angular JS framework version from 1.2.2 to latest 1.4.8 ?

Application stack : ASP.NET, web, api, Angular JS

- Is it a good decision to migrate from 1.2.2 to 1.4.8 versions ?
- Can you please provide a checklist or important points I should think 
  before the migration ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to go through the Migration pages for 1.2 - 1.3 and 1.3 - 1.4 and make sure if you are using any of the (very few) breaking changes that were introduced, that you mitigate those cases:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/guide/migration
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/guide/migration

This hasn't been updated for 1.5.0 yet since it is still in RC status.

Most of the breaking changes seem to be around the ngAnimate module.

After you do migrate, you will want to then take advantage of the new features added (particularly in 1.3- one way bindings).